# When I trying to send email via ACTION_SEND No Activity found to handle intent What's Wrong?

Tags: android, email, android-intent, android-activity

What is the solution of No Activity Problem and this is Error Message content
"No Activity found to handle Intent {act=android.intent.actoin.SEND tyb= plain/text"(has extras)} " ?

```
try {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailtxt.getText());
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subtxt.getText());
        intent.setType("plain/text");
        intent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messtxt.getText());
        startActivity(intent);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are either `no email application` or other social application installed on your device you trying `ACTION_SEND`. If it's not the case then try below code.

```
Intent ShareEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            ShareEmail.setType("message/rfc822");
            ShareEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "YOUR SUBJECT HERE");
            ShareEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "YOUR MESSAGE HERE");
            try {
                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(ShareEmail,"CHOOSE EMAIL CLIENT"));
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {
                Toast.makeText(ACTIVITY CONTEXT,"NO APP TO HANDLE THIS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
```

Comment: But What about Email app that is installed by default :

Comment: It Works on  my Real device :)

Comment: I didn't expect that this code can't performs via Email app that installed by default on the most android devices .!
At All Thank You Nitin Misra :) (Y)